# Azure Active Directory Premium P2 licenses

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

If I have an Azure Active Directory with 10 users and I want the benefits of the Advanced Security Reporting provided by AAD Premium P2, do I need 10 P2 licenses (one for each user) or 1 P2 license, for the user that will do the reporting/auditing.

I ask because the pricing states $10.95 per user, per month so I need to know how many users it will base the monthly fee on.

Comment: After buying Azure AD P2 Product, you may obtain 100 avaliable licenses. You can assign them to each user.

Comment: Oh, so it looks like there's something about purchasing the "product" I didn't understand then thanks. So for small tenants like this is won't be an issue?

Comment: Except the pricing says $10.95 per user, per month. Are you simply charged for allocated licenses?

Comment: Sorry for my unclear comment. You can choose how many users need this licenses and buy the product.  AAD Premium P2 is one Office 365 subscription. You  can choose how many users needed when you paying it. After purchasing , you will get same counts of licenses as you choosed befere. Then you can assign them to users.

Comment: For your scenario, you just need to buy the license with 10 users. So, you are charged for counts of  licenses you bought.